# How to use own protocol in hyperlinks in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, richtextbox

The hyperlinks that I add must be one of the standard protocol hyperlinks. By that mean it should be http://, https://, ftp://, file:// etc.

Is it possible to add my own protocol say ref:// or something like that in RTF text?

for your references,

while i typing the existing protocol (http,https,..) , it will be considered as a link,
[image]

I want to know, is it possible to achieve this with my own hyperlinks like below image?
[image]

Please give your valuable suggestions,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you mean in html with the `<a>` tag?

Comment: You can [register an application to a URI Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445139/3110834)

Comment: Take a look at this example: [Url Scheme Sample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/UrlSchemeSample).

Answer (score 1):

```
        private string editlLink(string link, string editWith) //link -> link to edit, editWith -> the protocol you want
        {
            return editWith + link.Substring(link.IndexOf(':'), link.Length - link.IndexOf(':'));
        }
```

And call it like this:

```
        string edittedLink = editlLink("https://afnanmakhdoom.com", "ftp");
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, RichTextBox will show the hyperlink when that link has the https:\, http:\ ..etc i.e.default protocols which are known by the system. The RichTextBox only supports the following protocols alone,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787991(v=vs.85).aspx

- callto
- file
- ftp
- gopher
- http
- https
- mailto
- news
- notes
- nntp
- onenote
- outlook, prospero, tel, telnet, wais, webcal

Seems that there is no support to show the own protocol as the hyperlink in the RichTextBox. Refer the below link,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/08/31/automatic-richedit-hyperlinks/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks/

Note

For the workaround, you can underline and text color as the blue for the own protocol hyperlink.