# how to run my application with short url like Microsoft Store

Tags: winforms

Microsoft Store uses a simple way to open the program via the link in Windows 10, such as if searching this `ms-windows-store://` in the search field will open Microsoft Store, can I do the same thing for any program? Or it is only for Microsoft programs

Comment: A WinForms example having setup project to register custom URL scheme: [Start application from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445139/3110834)

Comment: For WinForms or WPF: [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: For UWP: [Handle URI Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 0):

URI schemes are available for all apps not only Microsoft ones, for example, you can launch **Steam** using this URI *steam://* ,or launch a specific game *steam://rungameid/444200*

**Reserveded file and URI scheme names**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reserved-uri-scheme-names

**Registering an Application to a URI Scheme in windows 10**

[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694642/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-in-windows-10)