# Using the HttpClient class with a custom url scheme in C# and WindowsForms

Tags: winforms, dotnet-httpclient, url-scheme

I would like to use the HttpClient class in my WinForms application with a custom scheme uri like

vis://justiz/X6080/6%20A%201%2f21

The custom url protocol vis has already been registered in the Windows registry.

When I try an http get with the HttpClient class (namespace *System.Net.Http*) I'll get an "only http or https scheme is allowed" error obvisously:

```
httpClient = HttpClient()
httpClient.getAsync("vis://justiz/X6080/6%20A%201%2f21")
```

Is there any way to make the HttpClient class work with custom url protocols?

I would like to avoid using the WebBrowser control or a simple start process.

Comment: You most likely want to use the custom uri scheme with `Process.Start`, because it's not a `HTTP` request and there will not be a http server to respond the request; instead, you assign this uri scheme to an application and the application knows what to do with the uri. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445139/3110834).

Comment: The example is really helpful. If you would have posted this as an answer I could make this the accepted answer